# Select a cell depending on value from UF Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

New to VBA i'm still gathering as much knowledge as I can (And moving forward) but I'm stuck.

So basically I have a excel sheet called "Data" (A database) where I have Client name on the column 1st row and under each a series of data (Age, sex, height etc.).

On the other hand I have a "Userform1" which is used to update data, each information is in a TextBox exepct for the client name you'd choose from a "ComboBox2". (You cannnot delete or add a client).

My goal is: Once the form is filled, I'd like my code to find the client cells (From the combobox) and then store data associated by offsetting one cell under and overwrite and once again.

(I might not be clear but EN is not my native language and, well VBA neither).

My code attempt:

```
Private Sub Target_click() 'Target Button is the button used to update data

    With ComboBox2
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range (ComboBox2.Value)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value.Activate 'TBox1 = Age
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox2.Value.Activate 'TBox2 = Sex
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox3.Value.Activate 'TBox3 = Height
    ... Etc ...
    End With

End Sub
```

Thx all.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

The idea behind this is that you store the form's information in variables, then look for the sheet's data and update it.

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Target_Click()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim resultRange As Range

    Dim clientName As String
    Dim clientAge As Variant ' use long if you have validated the textbox to be numeric
    Dim clientSex As String
    Dim clientHeight As Variant ' use long if you have validated the textbox to be numeric

    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Gather forms data
    clientName = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    clientAge = Me.TextBox1.Value
    clientSex = Me.TextBox2.Value
    clientHeight = Me.TextBox3.Value

    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set searchRange = targetSheet.Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

    ' Find the client
    Set resultRange = searchRange.Columns("A").Find(clientName)

    ' Exit if didn't find anything
    If resultRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' If found, update cells
    With resultRange
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = clientAge
        .Cells(1, "C").Value = clientSex
        .Cells(1, "D").Value = clientHeight
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works